# How to set minimum window size in eel python

Tags: python, eel

I am using the eel python. When the window is in fullscreen, and I drag the title bar down (which should reduce the screen size), what happens is that the width becomes about 1 px; I can only see a very thin vertical line and sometimes it disappears out of nowhere, but the window is still active.

[A very thin line when the eel python window is minimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZgLX.png)

How can I set the minimum size of the window with eel python?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the window's height you can use the size property like this:

```
import eel
eel.init('web')
eel.start('youfile.html', size=(height, width))
```

Hope that you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

add the next line in your html file head :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Write JS function

```
window.onresize = function (){
    if (window.outerWidth < 1200 || window.outerHeight < 800){
        window.resizeTo(1200, 800);
    }
}
```